# Switch between Screens of an Android Application from a third class

Tags: java, android, android-activity, screen, android-screen-support

I want to know how to switch between screens from another class, here comes an example:

I have 3 classes:

Class screen1 extends Activity{...}

Class screen2 extends Activity{...}

Class switch{}

so, the class switch is called in screen1, finishs it and start another activity, the screen2.

That's the scope of my question, to be more especific my "switch" class is handlering headset button events, so I need this class.

Thanks!

--edit

```
public MediaButtonIntentReceiver() {
    super();
}

@Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String intentAction = intent.getAction();
        if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {

            Toast.makeText(context, "BUTTON PRESSED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            changeScreen();
            abortBroadcast();

        }

    }
```

I need to implement the changeScreen() method...

```
public void changeScreen (Context c, Intent i){
        Intent change = new Intent (c ,Screen2.class);
        c.getApplicationContext().startActivity(change);
    }
```

doesn't work like that!

Comment: and why do you need that o.O, use intents and make you life easier..

Comment: look now why I need it

Answer (score 1):

These `screens` are `Activities`. And you can switch between them by using `startActivity()` method. See: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html Please go through some tutorials about Android basics and also check the [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com) website

Comment: is not that simple, man!
I can't how to create the Intent in the switch class???
in the tutorial they used

Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);

It does not work

Comment: Did you add DisplayMessageActivity in your AndroidManifest? Also, what does `it does not work` mean?